# How to make buffer file names unique when mutiple instance of emacs are running

Tags: uniquify

The package `uniquify` has an interesting feature that when visiting two files with the same name, it shows in the mode-line a uniquified version of their name.
For example if we have two files with the paths `.../directory1/file.txt` and `.../directory2/file.txt` it shows in the mode-line something like `directory1/file.txt` and `/directory2/file.txt` not just `file.txt`.
It suffices to put this in the intit file:

```
(require 'uniquify)
```

Unfortunately this only works in a single instance of emacs.
Is there any way to have this feature when several instance of emacs are running? I mean how to uniquify the names in all frames and buffers opened in these instances.

Comment: Why do you need several instances of emacs in the first place? Can't you use `emacsclient` and `server-start` instead? Maybe, with multiple frames?